# User input row and column size for a 2-D array with Random numbers filling it C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, multidimensional-array, random, user-input

Hi I am very new to coding and was trying to figure out how to create a 2d array. That asks the user to input row and column size than fills those chosen row and column sizes with random numbers. After days of trying to figure it out I decided to come on here for help. Here is what I have so far, its all over the places I KNOW.

```
                char row = 'i';
                char column = 'j';
                int[,] twoDarray = new int[row, column];
                
                int min = 0;
                int max = 100;
                Random randNum = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < twoDarray.Length; ++i)
                
                for (int j = 0; j < twoDarray.Length; ++j) 
                
                {
                   twoDarray[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(In.ReadLine());
                }
```

Comment: What's your question? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953),

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question. I will assume that it is a console application. In that case, the code could look like:

```cs
          int row, column;
            
           string rowVal;
            Console.Write("\nEnter Number of Rows: ");
            rowVal = Console.ReadLine();            

            string colVal;
            Console.Write("\nEnter Number of Columns: ");
            colVal = Console.ReadLine();            

            bool allGood = true;
            if(!int.TryParse(rowVal, out row))
            {
                allGood = false;
                Console.Write("Number of Rows is wrong: ");
            }


            if (!int.TryParse(colVal, out column))
            {
                allGood = false;
                Console.Write("Number of Columns is wrong: ");
            }

            if (!allGood)
                throw new Exception("Wrong input data"); //or just return from your method

            int[,] twoDarray = new int[row, column];

            int min = 0;
            int max = 100;
            Random randNum = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < twoDarray.GetLength(0); ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < twoDarray.GetLength(1); ++j)
                {
                    twoDarray[i, j] = randNum.Next(min,max);
                }
            }
```